# clojure cycles returning nil in map-indexed

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a cycle based Fizz Buzz in clojure.  It seems to work for the values that are not Fizz or Buzz, but for the values that are Fizz and Buzz it returns nil.

Code:

```
(ns fizz-buzz.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn fizz-buzz [value]
  (let [fizz (cycle ["" "" "Fizz"])
        buzz (cycle ["" "" "" "" "Buzz"])
        fb (map str fizz buzz)]
    (nth (map-indexed 
           (fn [i v] 
             (if (clojure.string/blank? v)
               (str (+ i 1)
               v)))
           fb)
         (- value 1)))
```

Tests:

```
(ns fizz-buzz.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [fizz-buzz.core :refer :all]))

(deftest value-2-will-return-2 
  (testing "2 will return the string 2"
    (is (= "2" (fizz-buzz 2)))))

(deftest value-4-will-return-4 
  (testing "4 will return the string 4"
    (is (= "4" (fizz-buzz 4)))))

(deftest value-3-will-return-fizz
  (testing "3 will return the string Fizz"
    (is (= "Fizz" (fizz-buzz 3)))))

(deftest value-5-will-return-buzz
  (testing "5 will return the string Buzz"
    (is (= "Buzz" (fizz-buzz 5))))
```

The first two tests work (2 and 4), but the Fizz and Buzz test do not work.  I am sure I do not understand how map-indexed works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very slight bracket misplacement in your `if` statement. 
This means that you have no `else` case to your `if` (hence the `nil` result)

Try rewriting:

```
(if (clojure.string/blank? v)
           (str (+ i 1)
           v)))
```

As:

```
(if (clojure.string/blank? v)
           (str (+ i 1))
           v))
```

ps - it looks like you've understood map-indexed fine :)

Comment: An editor that (auto-)indents to Clojure to convention really helps with avoiding and finding such errors. For example, I use `vi` with `vim-clojure-static`, which places the `v` under `(+ i 1)` when the original is reindented, giving a clear visual signal that `v` is an argument to `str` instead of `if`. I'm sure Emacs, etc, does similar.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel.  I cannot believe I missed that.

A. I am coming back to vi after not using it for about 10 years.  I'll have to check out vim-clojure-static.  Thank you all.